# Why doesn't Websphere 9 detect Annotated mappedName value for EJBs?

Tags: java, annotations, ejb-3.0, websphere-9

Following is my Sample Code:

**AddStatelessBean.java:**

```
@Stateless(name = "AddStatelessBean", mappedName="ASBean")
@Remote(AddStatelessBean.class)
@LocalBean
public class AddStatelessBeanImpl implements AddStatelessBean {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

My Calling Code:
**CallAddBean.java:**

```
public static AddStatelessBean getAsbByName() throws Exception {
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        AddStatelessBean asbObj = (AddStatelessBean) initialContext.lookup("ASBean");
        return asbObj;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: VRDWIN7WAS9Node03Cell/nodes/VRDWIN7WAS9Node03/servers/server1, name: ASBean: First component in name ASBean not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
```

BUT, if I go to Websphere Admin Console -> Applications -> Websphere Enterprise Applications ->  -> EJB JNDI Names and assign the same JNDI name there and try to lookup, it is working.

I don't want to do that extra step or configure any XMLs (ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml) for making that happen during App Deployment itself.

How do I make this binding from pure JAVA Code itself? My main motive is to make my code run Server independent.

Comment: mappedName is kind of vendor-specific annotation, despite the fact it is in EJB specification. If you want your application to be server-independent consider to use lookup instead.

Comment: @AlexSergeenko, but even for using lookup, I'll need a JNDI name, right? And each Server has its own way in which it creates the JNDI name - which is my problem.